# Action Bar icon not showing in Fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add a logout icon on the action bar of the fragment, but nothing shows.

Snippet from my Fragment:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionmenu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.logout_button:
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
                getActivity().finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

My `res\menu\actionmenu.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout_button"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_exit_to_app_black_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="" />
</menu>
```

I've been trying many things but it does not seem to work. Please help.

Comment: Hey bk23, you should post your edit as an answer instead - see [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267434) on Meta StackOverflow for more info.

Comment: Hi Edric, I've posted it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may directly use :

```
<Toolbar
    id="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>
in your Fragment view.
```

And than in your fragment on create view methode you can do this

```
Toolbar toolbar= view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar)         `toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.actionmenu.xml);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want add an icon in your toolbar, right?

Something like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
    settingsToolbar = findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(settingsToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.close);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    Drawable backArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back_arrow);
    backArrow.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(backArrow);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings");
```

I hope that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem. If anyone has this problem, just check your manifest file for `android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar"`. I removed this and it worked for me.